# php.ini 500 error when register_globals = On

Tags: php, php.ini

i am using PHP Version 5.4.44 and have a setting in my php.ini as

## register_globals = Off

i am trying to set it as  register_globals = On

but it is not working and  through me an error as 500

please help me.

Comment: Did my answer http://serverfault.com/a/718097/101203 solve your question?  If so, I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted so I get credit and also so people in the future who read this know that it was a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That directive was removed as of PHP 5.4.0 (see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) so you can't have it in your php.ini at all.

If you really need register_globals functionality, you could use an auto_prepend_file which loops through $_GET / $_POST / $_COOKIE / etc. and creates variable names based on what is in each of those, but be sure you understand the security implications of using register_globals and are sure you really need it before doing so.